# Asp.Net MVC Application build error in TFS

Tags: tfs

when I build Asp.net MVC Application in TFS Server.

I am getting this error

> Compling sources for any CUP/Release
>
> Project TFSBuild.proj is building 'A.sln' with default traget

What is this casue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using TFS2008/5 so open the TFSBuild.proj file from source control and look for something in it like this:

```
<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/A.sln">
  <Targets></Targets>
  <Properties></Properties>
</SolutionToBuild>
```

Change the A.sln to the name of your MVC solution and then try again.  Don't forget that the path to the solution will be relative to where the TFSBuild.proj file is located.